# How to remove the unwanted entries from the boot menu?

Tags: boot, grub2

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there a way to remove/hide old kernel versions?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/2793/is-there-a-way-to-remove-hide-old-kernel-versions)

When my system boots up, a big list of some 6 options are shown other than the Windows OS option.

They are like :

```
Ubuntu 10.04- linux kernel 2.6.32-25  
Ubuntu 10.04- linux kernel 2.6.32-25 (recovery)  
Ubuntu 10.04- linux kernel 2.6.32-26  
Ubuntu 10.04- linux kernel 2.6.32-26 (recovery)  
...etc  
Memory Test..  
Windows XP Professional
```

How to remove the unwanted entries from this list?