# GRUB/BURG listing a lot of os's

Tags: grub2, dual-boot, burg

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to remove the unwanted entries from the boot menu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/15318/how-to-remove-the-unwanted-entries-from-the-boot-menu)

I guess I've got more than one ubuntu installation (either two or three) along with a windows 7 installation. Each of the ubuntu installations also list something extra (maybe like a safe mode?) within grub.

Firstly, how do I remove the ubuntu installations I don't use? (how do I first identify the one I do use? I log into it after booting it, but how do I delete the others)

Also, how do I leave just a Windows 7 option and an Ubuntu option?

Comment: Duplicate of: [How to remove the unwanted entries from the boot menu?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/15318/how-to-remove-the-unwanted-entries-from-the-boot-menu)

Answer (score -1):

just edit the file menu.lst located at /boot/grub

but first you have to create a backup of this file using for example this command

```
# cp /boot/grub/menu.lst menu.old
```